# top n most visited pages using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write most efficient sql to get an result from below data

```
Name,Age,URL
A,20,abc.com
B,12,ghi.com
C,25,def.com
D,21,abc.com
E,22,ghi.com
F,23,jkl.com
G,24,def.com
H,20,jkl.com
I,19,ghi.com
J,19,abc.com
K,22,def.com
L,16,jkl.com
M,15,def.com
N,27,jkl.com
O,26,abc.com
P,50,jkl.com
Q,12,def.com
R,56,abc.com
S,22,def.com
T,24,abc.com
U,35,jkl.com
V,45,ghi.com
W,20,abc.com
X,19,jkl.com
Y,18,abc.com
Z,65,ghi.com
```

I want top 5 urls where number of users visited most age from 18 to 25.

What would be the most efficient way to do that..rather than writing all inner queries step by step like first filter age, than group and count...?

Output schema would be
URL(Top-5), CountOfUsers(18-25)

Thanks

Comment: What if there's a tie for fifth place?

Comment: I don't know if it is important in that use case but you could do a wrapping select which groups again on the name count and use group_concat for the urls. Then u get a list of urls in each row were you have a tie.

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient way other than grouping.

```
select count(name), url
  from <tablename>
 where age >= 18 and age <= 25
 group by url
 order by count(name) dsc
 limit 0, 5
```

The only way to speed this up from my point of view is to use clusters and/or indices!
At least no inner query is necessary.

Comment: hmmm Okieee..!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you,

```
select top 5 NameCount = Count(name), url 
from (select name, url
        from [tablename] where age >= 18 and age <= 25) dd
group by url
order by count(name) desc
```